# Theming certain pages in drupal

Tags: drupal, tabs, themes

I need to theme tabs on a certain number of pages "user/*". If i simply use theme_menu_local_task in template.php, it will use the function on all pages, not only on "user/*".
Is there a way to theme only "user/" pages and leave others alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach:

```
function mytheme_menu_local_task($link, $active = FALSE) {
    // for paths you want to override the theme:
    if ($_GET['q'] == 'certain/path') {
        return '... my theme ...';
    }
    // for other _normal_ paths:
    else {
        return theme_menu_local_task($link, $active);
    }
}
```

Note you have to call return theme_menu_local_task() directly or your code will trapped in an infinite recursive calls.

Comment: WOrks great, stupid me didn't think to use IF in the function, not before the function.
I've also modified it a bit, to use if(arg(0) == 'user') for example, so all paths that start with user/ will get it.